# foreach sort data into combobox

Tags: c#, list, sorting, if-statement, foreach

I want to loop through a list of `Person` items.  If a person is entered more than once in that list I only want to display his name once in a combobox.  The code that I have displays the person's name more than once, because the same person is not entered directly after one another in the list. Here is my code:

```
Person equalPerson = new Person();

foreach (Person PersonItem in _listAllData)
{
    if (PersonItem.FirstName != equalPerson.FirstName)
    {
        cboSelectClient.Items.Add(PersonItem);
    }
    equalPerson = PersonItem;
}
```

Could you please give me some hints on what I could do?

Answer (score 2):

```
cboSelectClient.Items.AddRange(
            _listAllData.Select(x=>x.FirstName).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: this will fill the combobox with all names but removing duplicates, which is not what he/she wants. i think he/she wants to add to the combobox if it appears twice, ie is a duplicate.

Comment: @FredrikRedin No, I'm pretty sure OP just wants to eliminate duplicates; it was just worded a little weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use **Contains** function

```
if( !cboSelectClient.Items.Contains( PersonItem.FirstName ) )
{
    cboSelectClient.Items.Add( PersonItem.FirstName );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if the name of person is already in the combo box, dont add other .
you can use contains  method for this purpose.
if(!cboSelectClient.Items.Contains(PersonItem))
// add now

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
List<string> duplicateFirstnames = _listAllData
                .GroupBy(o => o.FirstName, (key, group) => group)
                .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
                .Select(group => group.FirstOrDefault().FirstName)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Person entity has an Id:

```
cboSelectClient.Items.AddRange(_listAllData.Select(person => new { person.Id, person.Name}).Distinct().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this linq to add distinct PersonItem to ComboBox. Only the first item will be added to ComboBox if any duplicate FirstName occurs :

```
var distinctPerson = (from person in _listAllData
                      group person by person.FirstName into g
                      select g.FirstOrDefault()
                      ).ToArray();
cboSelectClient.Items.AddRange(distinctPerson);
```